# difference between presentViewController and UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Please tell the difference between `presentViewController` and `UiNavigationController`? Could I use `presentViewController` instead of `UINavigationController` to navigate different views in the app?
Whats the scenario to use either?

Comment: please think about rating some of these answers if they were of any help to you thanks.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`presentViewController` offers a mechanism to display a so-called modal view controller; i.e.,  a view controller that will take full control of your UI by being superimposed on top of a presenting controller.

`UINavigationController` offers a much more flexible mechanism where you can push a new controller, and later pop it, so to go back to the previous one, in a ordered way. Imagine that controllers in a navigation controller will just build a sequence from left to right.

I think that `presentViewController` is most suitable for use with just *one* view controller being presented at a time. You can surely use it to stack more view controllers one on top of the other (and thus sort of "mimic" a poor-man's navigation controller), but my bet is you will quickly find something not working as you expected.

Specifically, an example of such limitation is the following: when you dismiss a modal view controller (in order to "close" it), all of your modally presented view controllers (from the same presenting controller) will also be dismissed at once. So you simply will not be able to implement a "go back"/navigation like functionality.

So, it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the concise and accurate answer!

Comment: glad to have helped but don´t forget to accept the answer if you found it useful!

Comment: @sergio: I am learning iOS. I have the same question. As I know, presentViewController/dismiss also maintain a navigation stack too. Both UINagivationController & presentViewController-dismiss method Only support 1 view controller visible ( presenting) at a time. So It seems that your answer is not very clear. Sorry If this wondering is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I reworded my answer to make it clearer, I hope, when explaining the thing about using just 1 view.

Answer (score 27):

A `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` that manages a stack of view controllers and adds a back button etc.

`presentViewController` is a method of the `UIViewController` class you use to present a modal view controller.

Comment: You could hide the navigation bar, in which case the navigation controller performs the same role as a modal presentation, doesn't it? Both maintain a stack -- a modally presented controller can present another controller modally, resulting in a stack. So, it seems that the difference between modal presentation and a navigation controller aren't as clear as your answer says.

Answer (score 5):

The `UINavigationController` maintains a navigation stack for you. You are then able to navigate through hierarchical content.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you use `UIViewControllers` `presentViewController` method you are basically just replacing the view controller. no navigation stack is maintained for you.

Comment: Are you sure No navigation stack if we use presentViewController. If you call "dismiss__", You will navigate to Previous viewController instance. It means both method will maintain navigation stack.

Comment: presentViewController does NOT replace the previous view controller. The older controller will be there when you dismiss the presented view controller. Besides, as Loc said, a modally presented controller can in turn present another modally, producing a stack.

Answer (score 3):

UINavigationController is a class, presentViewController is an instance method of UIViewController (iOS 5 + ), of which UINavigationController is a subclass.

pushViewController is a comparable method to presentViewController. It is an instance method of UINavigationController, for iOS 2 +

Comment: Please explain what the pros and cons of these two methods are, not just which class each method is a member of.