# navigationController is nil,when push the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, navigationcontroller

There are three `viewController`, `MainViewController` `ViewControllerB` and `ViewControllerC`. 
`MainViewController` will be loaded when the app launch.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    MainViewController * main = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:main];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    return YES;       
}
```

and there is a `button` on the `MainViewController`, present `ViewControllerB`,

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController];
ViewControllerB * vcb=[[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[rootViewController presentViewController:vcb animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After the `ViewControllerB` appear, click the button push `ViewController`C.
but the `navigationController` is `nil`. It can't push `ViewControllerC`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES];
```

Comment: You did `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, so that's normal. Didn't you wanted to do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcb animated:YES];` instead?

Comment: @Larme Actually vcB is a section and vcC is sub section of B. So I use present at first.Is there any solution？

Comment: You need to embed `ViewControllerB` in a `UINavigationController` or it won't have a navigationController itself. Then `UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vcb]; [rootViewController presentViewController:vcb animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: thank you ,It seems work. But do you mean [rootViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil] ? It's a little different from your code @Larme

Comment: That's what I meant, I forgot to replace `vcb` copy/pasting the last line.

Comment: Here is another question, why the ViewController navigationController is nil when using present?  @Larme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You have the MainViewController (**mvc**), which is embedded in a **NavigationController**;
2. Then, on **mvc** you have the following code:

   `[rootViewController presentViewController:vcb animated:YES completion:nil];`

   You are calling `presentViewController` on the current ViewController, which will **modally present** the next ViewController, in this case ViewControllerB (**vcb**);
3. Finally, you try to access the **NavigationController** inside ViewControllerB (**vcb**) in order to push ViewControllerC (**vcc**), with the following code:

   `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES];`

The problem is that **vcb** is not aware of the **NavigationController**, since `presentViewController` presents the view controller modally, outside the existing navigation stack. Thus, resulting in a *nil* **NavigationController** in **vcb**.

You can refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14233252/9323816](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233017/difference-between-presentviewcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller) for more information.