# Navigation controller is displayed from the second transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Why is the navigation bar not displayed immediately, but only after several transitions on the screens?

First Screen

[image: First Screen]

Second Screen

[image: Second Screen]

Third Screen

[image: Third Screen]

Fourth Screen

[image: Fourth Screen]

the transition between the storyboard is done by code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "detail", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! TwoViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: You should probably push your view controller instead of presenting

Comment: but how can I do this?

Comment: like this: `self.navigationController?.push(vc, animated: true)` pushing, pushes onto the navigation stack, but presenting works differently it presents over the top and doesn't use the parents navigation controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between presentViewController and UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233017/difference-between-presentviewcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are presenting the viewcontroller itself, it won't have any Navigation controller. If you need to present the viewcontroller with navigation controller, present NavigationController instead of viewcontroller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "detail", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationControllerID") as! UINavigationController
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

OR - wrap VC with NavController programmatically.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "detail", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! TwoViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nav, animated: true)
```

Comment: Both will work. But you have to use the same storyboard ID(navigationControllerID) in the code as well as Storyboard.